# Standard reference for "coarea formula"?

Tags: real-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

Is there a standard analysis reference for the first formula given in [these lecture notes](http://www.mai.liu.se/~vlatk48/teaching/teaching_vt2009/lectures_uu/PDE09-09.pdf):

$$\int_D h(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dt\int_{D_f(t)}\frac{h(y)}{|\nabla f(y)}\,dS_y$$
where $dS_y$ is the surface measure on $D_f(t)=\{x\in D:f(x)=t\}$? Here $D\subset \mathbb R^n$ is a bounded domain, $f\in C^1(D)$, and $h\in C^0(D)$.

I have found only results that use "Hausdorff measure", but this is too complicated for me.

Comment: Evans-Gariepy, "Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions". The *standard* reference is "Geometric measure theory", by Federer.

Comment: take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_coarea_formula The rest of your link is quite basic, I imagine there are undergraduate PDE books that do everything you want.